# I'm looking for a fantasy book with a female lead. Her mother has her isolated from civilization (for political reasons) a man shows up

Tags: story-identification

The mom tries to run him off (making it cold, snakes in his sleeping bag, thorns, etc). They end up married and fight in an arena. He dies. The female lead then falls for the mutual friend. They end up having to go on the run, have kids. I think there are horses that can turn into people, some kind of flying creatures, and wolf babies. They also travel through a desert made of gems.